# ngrx testing effects action failure

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-test

I've got this effect

```
login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.login),
      exhaustMap((action) =>
        this.service.login(action.credentials).pipe(
          map((data: LoginResponseDto) => {
            localStorage.setItem('__AUTH__', JSON.stringify(data));
            return AuthActions.loginSuccess({ data });
          }),
          catchError((error: ErrorDto) => {
            return of(AuthActions.loginFailure({ error }));
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

I was able to test loginSucces but not
the loginFailure

```
describe('login$', () => {
    it('should handle login and return a loginSuccess action', () => {
      const action = AuthActions.login({ credentials: loginRequestPayload });
      const outcome = AuthActions.loginSuccess({ data: loginSuccessPayload });

      testScheduler.run((helpers: RunHelpers) => {
        const { cold, expectObservable, hot } = helpers;
        actions = hot('-a', { a: action });
        const response = cold('-b|', { b: loginSuccessPayload });
        authService.login.and.returnValue(response);

        expectObservable(effects.login$).toBe('--b', { b: outcome });
      });
    });
    it('should handle login and return a loginFailure action', () => {
      const action = AuthActions.login({ credentials: loginRequestPayload });
      const outcome = AuthActions.loginFailure({ error: loginFailurePayload });

      testScheduler.run((helpers: RunHelpers) => {
        const { cold, expectObservable, hot } = helpers;
        actions = hot('-a', { a: action });
        const response = cold('-#|', {}, loginFailurePayload);

        authService.login.and.throwError(response);

        expectObservable(effects.login$).toBe('--(b|)', { b: outcome });
      });
    });
  });
```

I've got this message:

```
Expected $.length = 1 to equal 2. Expected $[0].frame = 1 to equal 2.
Expected $[0].notification.kind = 'E' to equal 'N'. Expected $[0].notification.value = undefined to equal Object({ error: Object({
message: 'Error' }), type: '[Auth Api] Login Failure' }). Expected
$[0].notification.error = null({ _subscribe: Function, messages: [
Object({ frame: 1, notification: Object({ kind: 'E', value: undefined,
error: Object({ message: 'Error' }) }) }), Object({ frame: 2,
notification: Object({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined
}) }) ], subscriptions: [  ], scheduler: TestScheduler({
schedulerActionCtor: Function, now: Function, actions: [  ], _active:
false, _scheduled: undefined, maxFrames: Infinity, frame: 1, index: 1,
assertDeepEqual: Function, hotObservables: [  ], coldObservables: [
<circular reference: Object> ], flushTests: [ Object({ actual: [
Object({ frame: 1, notification: Object({ kind: 'E', value: undefined,
error: <circular reference: Object> }) }) ], ready: true, expected: [
Object({ frame: 2, notification: Object({ kind: 'N', value: Object({
error: Object, type: '[Auth Api] Login Failure' }), error: undefined
}) }), Object({ frame: 2, notification: Object({ kind: 'C', value:
undefined, error: undefined }) }) ] }) ], runMode: true }) }) to equal
undefined. Expected $[1] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 2,
notification: Object({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined
}) }).
```

### UPDATE

This works

```
it('should handle login and return a loginFailure action', () => {
      const action = AuthActions.login({ credentials: loginRequestPayload });
      const outcome = AuthActions.loginFailure({ error: loginFailurePayload });

      testScheduler.run(({ cold, expectObservable, hot }: RunHelpers) => {
        actions = hot('-a', { a: action });
        const response = cold('-#|', {}, loginFailurePayload);
        authService.login.and.returnValue(response);
        expectObservable(effects.login$).toBe('--b', { b: outcome });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing the implementation, my guess would be that there's some difference in the timing of the emitted values. Also, I guess that the effect won't complete, so the expected marble should be `--b`

Also, I prefer not to use the marble syntax to test effects because they can be time insensitive - see my [blog post](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project#selectors) for an alternative.